# import graph tool doesn't work on iPython

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import, graph-tool

I installed graph-tool on ubuntu. When trying to import it in iPython I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named graph_tool.all
```

As I read in other posts it might be possible that I used a different version of python for installing graph-tools than the system version I'm using. My question is now, how do I check which version graph-tool is installed with and how do i change this in order to import it?
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score -1):

If you install using `pip` you can check

```
pip -V
```

result (for example)

```
pip 8.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

You should have `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.4`, etc. to install with different Python.

(in bash write `pip` and press `tab` twice to see all programs started with `pip`)

Comment: you can also open your terminal and open the interpreter for each version of python you have installed and try importing the module from there